# Assign fmt:formatDate output to a c:set variable

Tags: jsp, jstl

I want to do something like this:

```
<c:set var="strDate" value="<fmt:formatDate value='${obj.dateIn}' pattern='ddMMyyyy'/>"/>
```

to obtain the date as (formatted) string and assign it to a variable for later use but it isn't working, any ideas on how to do it in jsp-jstl?

The only way I find around it is to create a "fake" getter for the object java class that outputs the desired date as a String usign SimpleDateFormat.format(..) but me thinks it's not very orthodox and want to leave the underlying classes alone.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
<fmt:formatDate value=".." pattern=".." var="strDate" />
```

the `var` attribute is:

> Name of the exported scoped variable which stores the formatted result as a String.

Answer (score 1):

First format the date after assign dateFormated to variable

Put it this way:

```
<fmt:formatDate value='${obj.dateIn}' pattern='ddMMyyyy' var="searchFormated" />
<c:set var="strDate" value="${searchFormated}"/>
```